# git pull origin master failing with fatal error

Tags: git

I have created a git repository on the linux server, and I have successfully cloned it with `git clone` command.
However, when I run `git pull origin master` it throws the following error:

```
git pull origin master
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your `git` configuration file, which is `.git/config` in the directory of your project. Pay special attention to its `[remote]` section, as this is the part where your master server is defines. [This page](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section/) may be of help.